# Evaluating $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sum\limits_{r=1}^k\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{6^r}{2^{r+1}+3^{2r+1}}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, trigonometry, inverse-function

> Let $$S_k=\sum_{r=1}^k\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{6^r}{2^{r+1}+3^{2r+1}}\right)$$ Then find the value of $$\lim_{k\to\infty}S_k$$

---

I can clearly see that the value of the expression inside the $\tan^{-1}$ function lies in the interval $\left(\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. Also, I tried to apply the sum formula of   $\arctan$ function but in vain. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: With $a:=2^r,\,b:=3^r$ the $r$th term in $S_k$ is $\arctan\frac{ab}{2a+3b^2}$. I wish I could see a way to use that, together with $\arctan x+\arctan y=\arctan\frac{x+y}{1-xy}$, for a telescoping argument.

Comment: @J.G.- I really want it to telescope too! I would try $b=9^r$, and the difference of two arctans, but it's not coming together for me either. Or maybe we want some reciprocals in there, and should be looking at arccot's?